# Creating a horizontal navbar with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to make a bootstrap navbar that spans horizontally across the screen. However, when I attempt to do so, the navbar links stack vertically as I will show.

Here is the HTML / CSS I have implemented:

```css
body{
    padding-top: 90px;
    background-color: #dbdbdb;
}

#navMain{
    background-color: #db8606;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

#navbar-brand-image{
    height: 70px;

}

.nav-link{
    font-size: 165%;
    font-family: 'Sriracha', cursive;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
        <!-- CSS only -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Mono:ital,wght@1,500&family=Parisienne&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sriracha&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default fixed-top" id="navMain">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" id="navbar-brand-title" href="index.html"><img src="content/logo.png" id="navbar-brand-image" alt=""></a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
                    </li>

                    
                </ul>
            </div>
            
            
        
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

The result that I achieve looks like this:

[image: Unwanted result]

Instead, I want the links to span horizontally.

I tried using the W3schools tutorial at [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp) and it doesn't even recreate the same as what's on the site.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Navbars are really not that special, except they are fluid (100% wide) and hidden by default when printing. If you place the navbar inside a column grid it will align responsively to its parent; it also works with dropdowns:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-9">main content</div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <nav>
       <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" id="navbar-brand" href="#">#</a>
       </div>
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li>
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse" href="#dropdown">dropdown</a>
            <ul class="collapse" id="dropdown">
              <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>               
            </ul>  
          </li>
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a></li>
       </ul>
     </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/e2ur4wd0/**

Comment: thanks for your help. I am really new to bootstrap, appreciated :)

Comment: upon having a look at the code, it appears it is still creating a navbar that is descending down the page...

Comment: @JordanZdimirovic, ? Now I am confused :) You want a horizontal navbar vertically? I thought the problem was that you were not able to "stack" the navbar to the right? Can you be more precise? It suddenly hits me you want a "normal" navbar with the items stacked vertically to the right, and the "brand logo" to the left ...?

Comment: that's correct! I want the links to span FROM left TO right :)